# Calling a Web.Api Post call from asp.net C# applicaiton

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

so I'm pretty new to using Web.Api calls and have been reading up on them the last few days. In a nutshell I have a C# asp.net application that needs to post records to a Web.Api call that another group has setup for various applications to send records to that I need to interface with. Right now I have something that tries to work but I'm getting 'error 500: Internal server error' when I run things. I admit it could be on their end, but I wanted to make sure my end was correct as well.

So here is what I have. First I have a class I populate and send up to the wab.api call as that is what it is asking for

```
public class PackageData
{
    public string HostName { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public int SourceID { get; set; }
    public string PackageName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string BatchID { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReceivedTime { get; set; }

}
```

Here is the function I actually make the call with. Right now for testing purposes I populate a generic 'PackageData' object which I will eventually populate programatically

```
    public string Test_Update()
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://ServerName/Updates/");  
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();  
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        PackageData InstallPackage = new PackageData();
        InstallPackage.HostName = "ComputerName";
        InstallPackage.SerialNumber = "SerialNumber";
        InstallPackage.PackageName = "PackageName.EXE";
        InstallPackage.SourceID = 1;
        InstallPackage.UserName = "User";
        InstallPackage.BatchID = 1;
        InstallPackage.ReceivedTime = DateTime.Now;

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Package?UserName=UserID&Password=password", InstallPackage).Result;

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return response.Headers.Location.ToString();
    }
```

Is there anything glaring that looks wrong to anyone?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you experience right now? Exception thrown by response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() ? What is the status code ? Do you have the control over the code of the api //ServerName/Updates/ ?

Comment: Right now it's coming back with error 500: Internal server error. Like I sad before it's possible the issue is on their side, but i wanted to make sure my  side was correct.

The link I was given was http://Server/Updates/api/Package?UserName=UserID&Password=Password

I unfortunately have no control over the web.api side. I was told also as long as I get a 'success' returned I should be good.

Comment: InstallPackage.BatchID = 1; is of type string!

Comment: What does the web server log say?

Comment: If you are getting a 500, you are reaching the server, which is a good start. Next thing to look at is the formatting of your request but that is not HttpClient related, it goes down to have a detailed documention/support to know how to interact with the API.